# Least time - intensive way to print logs for a function (alternative / threaded method for print?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-multithreading

I'm trying to print a bunch of information about a function (or write that information to a file) every time it's called, for debugging purposes. Here is what I've been using so far:

```
# Logs function calls to dict and prints at end
from functools import wraps
from pprint import pprint


def Logit(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        returns = func(*args, **kwargs)
        pprint({"Func": func.__name__, "Args": args, "Kwargs": kwargs, "Returns": returns})
        return returns
    return inner
```

It's a basic decorator that just prints the function's name, arguments it was called with and it's returns. However, the `pprint` (or `print` for that matter) is a relatively slow function to run, and impacts performance significantly when the function is called multiple times a second.

Here is a showcase of what I mean:

```
from timeit import timeit

@Logit
def log_foo():
    return 2

def foo_without_logs():
    return 1

timeit(foo_without_logs, number=10000)
""" 0.0007391999999981635 """

timeit(log_foo, number=10000)
""" 0.24549239999998917 """
```

I want the `@Logit` decorator to not impact performance this significantly, if at all. I suspect the `threading` module might be of some use here, but I can't isolate the `pprint`/`print` statements and have them running apart from the main `Logit` thread. Here is a solution I've tried and been unable to implement:

```
def Logit(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        returns = func(*args, **kwargs)
        magical(pprint({"Func": func.__name__, "Args": args, "Kwargs": kwargs, "Returns": returns}))
        return returns
    return inner

"""
'magical' would seperate the print/pprint from the main thread, allowing it to run in parallel to the return lines
"""
```

About the overhead from having a decorator on, here it is - the print statements still take up by far the most time.

```
timeit(foo_without_logs, number=10000)
""" 0.0007391999999981635 """

timeit(foo_with_empty_decorator, number=10000)
""" 0.0014512000000077023 """
```

Comment: Try using `sys.stdout.write`. Basically, the `sys` module contains lower-level functions, and `print` is just a wrapper, but you will have to handle a lot of things manually, like flushing buffer, etc. You could read more about the `sys` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python logging performance comparison and options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520160/python-logging-performance-comparison-and-options)

Comment: @Salahuddin could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Please, first have a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sys-stdout-write-in-python/). Does this help?

Comment: IO is always going to be slow. Instead of writing directly inside your decorator you will want to add the logs to a queue that is handled somewhere else. (Can be another thread for example)

Comment: Sorry I'm replying so late! @blues could you provide a minimal example of what you mean?

Comment: @ShisuiOtsutsuki that helps, but not by much. Using the `timeit` module, and giving both empty strings, `sys.stdout.write` indeed performs `20%` better than `print`, but when giving them both **any characters or strings to print** they both have performance similar within `3%` in my testing.